# Fill a column's blank spaces with like values

Tags: vba

I'm trying to add excel files to an access database. I'd like to have each room name searchable by room number. Right now, if you query the room number, it only comes up with the row containing that room number, even though the rows below the room number also contain data for that same room... like so:

http://i802.photobucket.com/albums/yy304/Growler2009/Database_Fill_In.jpg

So, what I'd like to do is write a script that will scan through the room number column (Column 1)... each time the script lands upon a unique room number, it fills in the blank spaces below it with that same room number.

After:
http://i802.photobucket.com/albums/yy304/Growler2009/BlankSpace_FillIn.jpg

So far I've written this test script... but it doesn't seem to be working... Any tips?
Thanks!

```
RoomNumber = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    For RoomNumberRow = 1 To 5
        For ColIndex = 1 To 5

        If Cells(RoomNumberRow, ColIndex).Value = RoomNumber(RoomNumberRow) Then
        'Move down a cell
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        'changes that cell to the same room number
        Cells.Value = RoomNumber(RoomNumberRow)

    End If
Next RoomNumberRow
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the materialDescriptionColumn is not empty until the end of the list, and the roomNumberValue is not empty in the first row.

If all the columns have empty fields before the end of the list, a For loop would be an option.

```
counter = 'First row.

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(counter, materialDescriptionColumn).Value)
    roomNumberValue = Cells(counter, roomNumberColumn).Value

    If roomNumberValue = "" Then
        Cells(counter, roomNumberColumn) = roomNumber
    Else
        roomNumber = roomNumberValue
    End If

    counter = counter + 1
Loop
```